# MOSFET Behavior During Pulsed Operation

Tags: mosfet, switches, igbt

I am trying to use back-to-back MOSFETs/IGBTs to isolate my pulsed supply from my load. In theory, I will switch on the MOSFETs, and the pulsed supply will be attached directly to the load (but not on yet). Once my pulsed supply emits a single pulse through the MOSFETs, won't they turn off due to the sudden increase in Vgs? The pulse I am sending through is ~4 kV, so it is obviously MUCH more than my Vg voltage.

[image]

Comment: Need a schematic to see what you're doing.  Often back-to-back MOSFETs are connected common-source, and an isolated gate driver drives the gates with respect to the source.  If you don't mind slow turn on/off there are photovoltaic optocouplers that can drive Vgs, though you have to be careful with common mode dv/dt.

Comment: John, yes, you are correct how I was planning hooking them up. I've updated my question to include a screenshot. I am using 4 MOSFETs total, in order to reach the voltage level I was hoping for. Since there are 4, would I need to have 3 or 4 different gate drivers for this?

Comment: How do you stop the mosfets dying when you turn them off during a 4kV pulse because for sure they will surely die. Or, try and explain what you want to happen and forget about MOSFETs as a potential solution - there may be better ideas.

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying this earlier - the MOSFETs will not be turned off during any of the 4 kV pulses. The HV pulse will be very short (100 nS), relative to the on time of the MOSFETs (~100 uS). Ideally, the MOSFETs will turn on, then there will be a ~50 uS waiting time, then a short HV pulse through them, and then finally another ~50 uS waiting time, at which point the MOSFETs will turn off.

Comment: I think you would only need one gate driver from the gates to the common source point in the center.  However, the driver has to be isolated from the signal, and I don't know how you deal with the huge dv/dt you will have with your 4kV pulse.  I can imagine all kinds of ways that might make this very difficult.